# Testing no modifier method in Java using junit

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have the following method with no modifier declared exactly in my Column class.

```
float maximumActiveDutyCycle(ArrayList<Column> columns)
{
    // TODO: change public back to default
    float maximumActiveDutyCycle = 0.0f;
    for (Column column : columns)
    {
        if (column.activeDutyCycle > maximumActiveDutyCycle)
        {
            maximumActiveDutyCycle = column.activeDutyCycle;
        }
    }
    return maximumActiveDutyCycle;
}
```

But I also have the following test method in class TestColumn. I was wondering if someone could tell me how I should test my method since I don't know how to access it from the Test class. Thanks!

```
public void testMaximumActiveDutyCycle()
{
    this.column00.setActiveDutyCylce(1.1f);
    this.column01.setActiveDutyCylce(1.3f);
    this.column33.setActiveDutyCylce(1.35f);
    this.column57.setActiveDutyCylce(1.355f);
    Set<Column> columns = new HashSet<Column>();
    columns.add(column00);
    columns.add(column01);
    columns.add(column33);
    columns.add(column57);



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, your unit test class should reside in the same class path package as your class.

```
src/main/java/com/yourcompany/project <- your project's classes
src/test/java/com/yourcompany/project <- your unit tests
```

So in your unit test class, you could access the method that has package access visibility:

```
Column column = new Column()
column.maximumActiveDutyCycle(columns);
```

Code example:

src/**main**/java/sg/java/test

```
package sg.java.test;

public class Myclass {
    float maximumActiveDutyCycle() {
        return 0f;
    }
}
```

src/**test**/java/sg/java/test

```
package sg.java.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MyclassTest {
    @Test
    public void testMaximumActiveDutyCycle() {
        Myclass clazz = new Myclass();

        assertTrue(clazz.maximumActiveDutyCycle() == 0f);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Changed the unit test's class name, should be post fixed with `Test` instead of prefixed. While the method name should be prefixed with `test` by convention.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your method has default (package) scope.  Your test class must be in the same package as your `Column` class, in order for it to be visible.

Note that even if your `Column` class is in the `src/` folder and your tests are in the `test/` folder, as long as the package names are the same within the respective source folders, your class will be visible.

Comment: I did what you said and even imported my concrete Column class to my class TestColumn but I am still unable to access my default method in class Column.